# How to set SkinID to the TextBox in the UserControl's CodeBehind File?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, textbox

I am checking some condition in the GridView_RowCommand event. Based on the Condition I want to set SkinID or remove SkinID for the TextBox.

This is my Code:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["D1Variable"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            txtMRVD1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["D1"].ToString();
            txtMRVD1.ReadOnly = true;
            txtMRVD1.SkinID = "txtreadonly";            
        }
        else
        {
            txtMRVD1.Text = "";
            txtMRVD1.ReadOnly = false;
        }
```

But it throws the following error.

```
    "The 'SkinId' property can only be set in or before the Page_PreInit event for static controls. For dynamic controls, set the property before adding it to the Controls collection."
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, based on the error message, that you simply need to move that code to the `Page_PreInit` event.

However, as MSDN says:  "If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event."

You may need to get more creative in how you approach this - perhaps storing the information used to determine the skin id in Session.  I suggest getting familiar, if you're not already, with the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Here's an example that *might* work for you, or at least get you pointed in the right direction:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((string)Session["D1Variable"] == "0")
    {
        txtMRVD1.SkinID = "txtreadonly";
    }
}
```

You can then do the rest of your logic in the GridView RowCommand event.